# How to access to listelements of returnvalue in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I have some trouble accessing the return value of my function. The returnvalue is a list, and I want to have access to both of the list elements:

That's the working code:

```
f1  =  f2 1 2
f2 a b = [a,b]
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    print(f1)
```

To show the idea, this is what I want to do (that code does not work):

```
f1  =  [x,y] = f2 1 2
       if x == 42 then y * 23 else x

f2 a b = [a,b]
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    print(f1)
```

How can i get access to x and y in f1?

Comment: Your syntax in the second example is wrong, it looks like you write `f1` in an imperative style. Probably it is lacking a `let` statement.

Comment: I changed the text a little bit, to make it clearer that its "only the idea" of what I want, I dont know the right syntax for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more a matter of wrong syntax here: you use two `=` tokens for `f1`, and seem to write it in an imperative way.

We can here use a **`let` clause**:

```
f1 = let [x,y] = f2 1 2 in if x == 42 then y * 23 else x
```

or we can use a **`where` clause:**

```
f1 = if x == 42 then y * 23 else x
    where [x,y] = f2 1 2
```

Note that the above pattern matching is rather unsafe: a list can not give guarantees about its size. Usually in case the size is fixed, a tuple is a better option. We can thus reimplement it with tuples like:

```
-- with tuples
f1  = let (x, y) = f2 1 2 in if x == 42 then y * 23 else x

f2 a b = (a, b)
```